# Why does IGV turn a VCF QUAL of "." into -10?

Tags: vcf, variant-calling, igv

IGV is turning QUAL "." into -10 from this VCF of structural variations.  I'm wondering if this means anything or if I should report a bug to the IGV devs.

Here's a row from a VCF:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT SAMPLE

chrY    11292098    DUP00008569 C   <DUP>   .   PASS    IMPRECISE;SVTYPE=DUP;SVMETHOD=EMBL.DELLYv0.8.1;CHR2=chrY;END=56834684;PE=3;MAPQ=24;CT=5to3;CIPOS=-265,265;CIEND=-265,265    GT:GL:GQ:FT:RCL:RC:RCR:CN:DR:DV:RR:RV0/1:-5.71458,0,-20.0913:57:PASS:0:90774:0:-1:6:5:0:0
```

You see the QUAL value is "."

IGV reports it as -10

[image: igv screenshot]

(This call is probably a false positive but it's just an example. There are others)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they are treating the "." as a value of 1.  According to the [VCF spec](http://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) the quality is "−10log10 prob".  Where are you getting your QUALs from?  I have never seen the quals as a "." and IGV probably needs to do some translation into an int but a QUAL of -10 makes no sense.

I would report it and let them explain.

Comment: It's Delly structural variation caller, not a SNV caller so I guess the QUAL field wasn't what they wanted to use for quality of the call.  Still IGV should just report a "." or nothing not some random negative value.

Comment: The QUAL field is often `.` when a quality couldn't be assigned.